# ons-lazy-repeatで表示したons-listをons-pull-hookで更新したい。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

表題の通り、ons-lazy-repeatで表示したons-listをons-pull-hookで更新したく
下記公式ドキュメントのサンプルコードを動かし、いろいろ試したのですが
ドキュメントに記載されている情報のみでは対応が難しい状況です。どのように実装すればよいのでしょうか。

http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-lazy-repeat.html

Answer (score 1):

私も最初Onsen UIのドキュメントだけを見て、実装が難しかったのですが、よく調べてみるとCode Penにサンプルがあり、それを真似て実装してみたところ、正常に動かすことができました。良ければ、ご覧になってください。

http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/QwrGBm

Comment: Middleさん、ありがとうございます。
URLについて確認させていただいたのですが
ons-lazy-repeat表示後にons-pull-hookを実行し、ons-lazy-repeatで表示したリストを更新する手順は載っていないように見えるのですが、どちらに掲載されているのでしょうか。
(現状ons-lazy-repeatの表示自体は出来ており、そこからリストを更新するのが目的となります。)